# Store Json data to JSON file and save them in the CSV file

Tags: python, json, pandas

I tried this way but did not work

```
   with open("data.json", "a", encoding='utf-8') as f:
      json.dump(data,  f,ensure_ascii=False, indent=4 )
```

**But this problem occurs**

[image]

#2

**I want to convert from json to CSV**

**An example of what I want**

[image]

***Please tell me if this is possible***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both can be done with `pandas`

- To store json data in a .json file, use [`pandas.DataFrame.to_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html)
- To save json data in a .csv file, first use [`pandas.read_json`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.1.3/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) to read the data into a dataframe and then use [`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can't append JSON files together into a new JSON, because of the nature of the JSON format.

Instead of writing each object individually to the JSON file, you should collect all of the objects into a list, and write the list to the JSON file:

```
lst = []
for data in ...:
    lst.append(data)

with open("data.json", "w", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    #                   ^ notice "a" was changed to "w" here
    json.dump(lst, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)
```